# WordPress pagination, offset and count users with WP_User_Query()

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress I want to count all users, show users using offset and limit using WP_User_Query. So I am using ajax where user can select how many numbers of users should be shown and should show pagination.

So for that I am using this

```
$limit_args = array( 'number' => $request['length'], 'offset' => $request['start'] );


$args = array( 'orderby' => 'display_name', 'order' => 'ASC' );

$all_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$total_users = count($all_users->get_results());
$filtered = count($all_users->get_results());
```

Here I am getting the total users

But to limit the users and for offeset I am again using WP_User_Query. Like this

```
$data = array()
if( $filtered > 0 ) {
    $args = array_merge($args, $limit_args);
    $all_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    foreach ( $all_users->get_results() as $user ) {
        $user_data = array();
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

        $user_data[] = $user->display_name;
        array_push($data, $user_data);
    }
}
print_r($data); //Gets user data
```

So if you see I am using WP_User_Query() two times. So can someone tell me how to use at a time  to get the offset and limit with total users at a time.

Comment: According to the [`WP_User_Query` class reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/), there's no property or parameter to get the total users and the results in the same query. So you may want to try with a custom query using [`$wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/).

Comment: @NewUser and @Mithc There is a `count_total` parameter which can be used as an argument in `wp_user_query` to get the total number of user. Once you have got that you can call `set` method to set offset and limit and use `get_results`

Comment: @Faham shaikh can you please share some code? Because count_total gets the number of users as per the current query. So have can I use that with offset and limit?

Comment: @NewUser I have never really used this code but in theory something like this should work with your first query `$total_users = $all_users->get_total(); if($total_users > 0) { $all_users->set('number', $request['length']);$all_users->set('offset', $request['start']); $results = $all_users->get_results(); //Do Something}`

Comment: Let me know if this works.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Nope its not working at all.

Comment: Do you get a count at `get_total`?

Comment: Yes get_total() is showing total numbers of users.

Comment: @FahamShaikh you're right, I misunderstood/combined with `total_users`. Thanks!

Comment: @Mithc, we both learned something new from this. :)

Answer (score 1):

So I looked at the `WP_User_Query` behavior and the related `get_total` function and realized that although `set` function will work, you really don't need to use it.

The code you will need for things to work smoothly is as follows:

```
$user_count = 10;
$offset = 0;
if(isset($request['length'])) {
    $user_count = $request['length'];
}
if(isset($request['start'])) {
    $offset = $request['start'];
}
$args = array('number' => $user_count, 'offset' => $offset, 'orderby' => 'display_name', 'order' => 'ASC');
$all_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$total_users = $all_users->get_total(); //use this for pagination
$filtered = count($all_users->get_results()); //use this for determining if you have any users, although it seems unnecessary
$data = array()
if( $filtered > 0 ){
    foreach ( $all_users->get_results() as $user ) {
        $user_data = array();
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        $user_data[] = $user->display_name;
        array_push($data, $user_data);
    }
}
print_r($data); //Gets user data
```

If you do not want to set the `number` and `offset` parameters by default, you can do as following:

```
$args = array( 'orderby' => 'display_name', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$all_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$total_users = $all_users->get_total();
$all_users->set('number', $request['length']);
$all_users->set('offset', $request['start']);
$all_users->prepare_query();
$all_users->query();
$filtered = count($all_user->get_results());
//And whatever you want from here on
```

Good Luck!!

Comment: @NewUser Not sure if you figured this out on your own but if you didn't, this will work for you.